# Adding Biller billing_first_name to a footer message in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to add user name to the footer for customer emails.
I have other code which adds user name. as below.
Its worth noting that I am using functions.php from within a child theme.

```
   add_filter('woocommerce_email_subject_new_order', 'change_admin_email_subject', 1, 2);

    function change_admin_email_subject( $subject, $order )
    {
            $subject = sprintf( 'New Customer Order (# %s) from %s %s - %s', $order->id, $order->billing_first_name, $order->billing_last_name, $order->order_date );
            return $subject;
    }
```

now this works fine, however when I try to use similiar for the footer , I simply get errors or nothing at all.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', 'update_footer_for_emails');

function update_footer_for_emails( $email, $order )
{

        $customer = $order->get_billing_first_name();

        echo '<h1>' . $customer . ', please stay in touch</h1>';
}
```

is anybody able to explain why this isn't working, I have been breaking my head for 2 days on this now ..

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

well it seems I fixed this in the footer, by simply applying the following change.

```
// function to add a keep in touch note, as well as facebook and insta icons to emails

add_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', 'update_footer_for_emails');

function update_footer_for_emails( $order )
{
    $user_id = $order->object->get_billing_first_name();
    $order_id = $order->object->id;

        $email_greeting = sprintf( '<h1>Hi %s, please stay in touch</h1>', $user_id );
}
```

Although its fixed, I actually don't understand why this works ? is this because the object is passed into the footer but for the other templates, the object is already in scope ?